# is Searching possible in jTable? if yes then how? any example :)

Tags: vb.net, webforms, jquery-jtable

i am working with jTable
here is demos http://www.jtable.org/Tutorials/UsingWithAspNetWebFormsPageMethods#CreatePage
but i am not able to find the search option. can you help me.
is it searching possible in jTable, if yes, can anybody provide me example with code.
i am using jTable with VB asp.net Web Forms. 
 I will really appreciate it by marking your suggestion as answer, i really need it. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for this: http://www.jtable.org/Demo/Filtering

You can filter the table based on a search string.

Comment: ohh 10x bro.. it was there ;)

Comment: If it was the right answer for you, remember to accept it. :)